# Storing a class's type in file

Tags: c++

I have a class `NodeManager`. It basically keeps a list of `Node*`s and their connections to each other. Actually the Nodes it manages are classes derived from the `Node` class.
Now I want this `NodeManager` to be able to save and all its nodes to file and load it back.

The problem I am facing is how could I store what is the derived type of the Nodes.

I was thinking of something like storing the `typeid` of the derived class and keeping a list of possible types the `Node` can be derived to, but I have no idea how could I accomplish that.

Performance isn't a problem, in any case we are talking about <100 nodes.
The answer should work multiplatform on windows, linux and mac os.
I want the answer to make adding more node types trivial, if possible, without altering the code of the `NodeManager`.

Comment: Add an attribute to each type like you said, then add an overloaded "read()" function to each derived type that know how to read/parse itself.

Comment: Thats the idea, but how does the manager know, which class to allocate, and read? What I mean is what attribute to store, and how exactly, how to avoid the necessity of changing the `NodeManager` to know about new types

Comment: how about [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#pointers)

Comment: @yngum I don't see anything in boost::serialization that helps me in saving the actual type of the class, only the class itself. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @akaltar I never used it either, from the link it does save type of class and reconstruct them during deserialization.

Comment: @yngum Yes it seems you are right, I missed the part where it was talking about derived classes, please post this as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base class, create abstract virtual method that returns some kind of "ID". (string, int, enum, whatever).

In "save" method, write ID first, for all classes. You could embed ID writing into base class, so derived classes won't override this behavior.

```
typedef SomeType ClassId;

class Serializeable{
protected:
   virtual ClassId getClassId() const = 0;
   virtual void saveData(OutStream &out) = 0;
public:
   void save(OutStream &out){
       out << getClassId();
       saveData(out);
   }
};
```

Make a factory, that constructs required class given its ID.

--edit--

Example with factory (C++03 standard):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <utility>

typedef std::string ClassId;
typedef std::ostream OutStream;

class Serializeable{
protected:
    virtual void saveData(OutStream &out) = 0;
public:
    virtual ClassId getClassId() const = 0;
    void save(OutStream &out){
        out << getClassId();
        saveData(out);
    }
    virtual ~Serializeable(){
    }
};

class Derived: public Serializeable{
protected:
    virtual void saveData(OutStream &out){
        out << "test";
    }
public:
    virtual ClassId getClassId() const{
        return "Derived";
    }
};

typedef QSharedPointer<Serializeable> SerializeablePtr; //basically std::shared_ptr

SerializeablePtr makeDerived(){
    return SerializeablePtr(new Derived());
}

class ClassFactory{
protected:
    typedef SerializeablePtr (*BuilderCallback)();
    typedef std::map<ClassId, BuilderCallback> BuilderMap;
    BuilderMap builderMap;

    template<class C> static SerializeablePtr defaultBuilderFunction(){
        return SerializeablePtr(new C());  
    }

public:
    SerializeablePtr buildClass(ClassId classId){
        BuilderMap::iterator found = builderMap.find(classId);
        if (found == builderMap.end())
            return SerializeablePtr();//or throw exception

        return (*(found->second))();
    }

    void registerClass(ClassId classId, BuilderCallback callback){
        builderMap[classId] = callback;
    }
    template<typename T> void registerClassByValue(const T &val){
        registerClass(val.getClassId(), ClassFactory::defaultBuilderFunction<T>);
    }
    template<typename T> void registerClassWithTemplate(ClassId classId){
        registerClass(classId, ClassFactory::defaultBuilderFunction<T>);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ClassFactory factory;

    std::string derivedId("Derived");
    factory.registerClass(derivedId, makeDerived);
    SerializeablePtr created = factory.buildClass(derivedId);
    created->save(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Derived tmp;
    factory.registerClassByValue(tmp);
    created = factory.buildClass(derivedId);
    created->save(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    factory.registerClassWithTemplate<Derived>(derivedId);
    created = factory.buildClass(derivedId);
    created->save(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`QSharedPointer` is smart pointer class from Qt 4, roughly equivalent to `std::shared_ptr`. Use either `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `QSharedPointer` in your code.

Comment: I would like to see a factory implementation, where I can add types dynamically like `Factory.AddType( int, "int");`. If you can provide that, I will accept this answer as its simpler than using boost.

Comment: @akaltar: Added factory example.